# What is the difference between synthesize propertyname = _propertyname

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c. I create a property at .h header file of the class and then i synthesize.

What is the difference between

```
@synthesize propertyname;
```

and

```
@synthesize propertyname = _propertyname;
```

Both work but what is the purpose of using the first one or the second one.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need not write `@synthesize propertyname` anymore.

In Objective-C when you declare a property, compiler auto generates its accessor methods for you by default. These accessor methods can be getter and setter if property is both read and write property else just a getter if it's a readonly property.

Compiler uses internal variables (called iVar) under the hood of these accessor methods implementation. (You can obviously provide your own implementation of these accessor methods and also provide your own internal variables as well)

**What is the difference between `@synthesize propertyname;` and `@synthesize propertyname = _propertyname;`**

when you declare a `@synthesize propertyname;` compiler auto generates and uses an `iVar` named `propertyname` and uses it in its default accessor implementation and you can also use it as `propertyname` in your `.m` file as compiler has already declared it for you.

```
property = @"abcd";
```

when you declare a `@synthesize propertyname = _propertyname;` compiler auto generates and uses a iVar named `_propertyname` and uses it in its default accessor implementation and you can also use it as `_propertyname` in your `.m` file as compiler has already declared it for you.

```
_property = @"abcd";
```

Broadly speaking the general difference between the two statement is just the change in name of `iVar` (usage of it are different though)

> what is the purpose of using the first one or the second one.

As I already mentioned you need not use either of them in a normal usecase. Compiler already does that for you.

We used to write `@synthesize propertyname;` when we neither had any specific reservation about the name of `ivar` nor wanted to provide our own private variable as `ivar` to a specific property (Explained in detail below). This was simpler than explicitly specifying the name of `iVar` and we knew that compiler will generate an `ivar` with same name as property for us.

we typically wrote `@synthesize propertyname = _propetyname` when `@synthesize propertyname;` wasn't available or when we wanted our `iVar` to follow a specific nomenclature ('_' following name of property) or when we wanted to use our own private variable as `iVar` to a property.

In both the cases `@synthesize` was handy because it would relieve us from writing a boiler plate code like adding `setter` and `getter` methods for properties declared.

**How to use custom variable as `ivar` for a property?**

```
@interface SynthesizeExplorer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@end

@implementation SynthesizeExplorer
NSString *blaBlaName;
@synthesize name = blaBlaName;
@end
```

If you look at the `implementation` you will see that property `name` is backed by a internal variable named `blaBlaName` and not by the typical compiler generated ivar like `name` or `_name`.

As of today the only reason I see for the usage of `@synthesize` when you wanna use your custom internal variable to back the property you have declared. Otherwise I dont see any point in writing neither `@synthesize propertyname;` or `@synthesize propertyname = _propertyname;`

Comment: @stefanosn: Did this answer help?